# Error al intentar consumir API REST pokeapi

Tags: android, retrofit

estoy intentando consumir la api de [PokeAPI - JSON](http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon)

al parecer funciona perfecto pero intentando utilizar `retrofit` me manda msj de:

```
OnFailure: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb86735f0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
```

**Android**

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

//Interface
public interface PokeapiService {
    @GET("pokemon")
    Call<PokemonRespuesta> obteinerListaPokemon();
}

//Array de respuesta
public class PokemonRespuesta {
    private ArrayList<Pokemon> results;

    public ArrayList<Pokemon> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(ArrayList<Pokemon> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}

//...
public class Pokemon {
    private String name;
    private String url;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}

//obtencion de datos:
 private void obtenerDatos() {
        PokeapiService service = retrofit.create(PokeapiService.class);
        Call<PokemonRespuesta> pokemonRespuestaCall = service.obteinerListaPokemon();

        pokemonRespuestaCall.enqueue(new Callback<PokemonRespuesta>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PokemonRespuesta> call, Response<PokemonRespuesta> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    PokemonRespuesta pokemonRespuesta = response.body();
                    ArrayList<Pokemon> listaPokemon =  pokemonRespuesta.getResults();
                    for (int i =0; i < listaPokemon.size(); i ++){
                        Pokemon p = listaPokemon.get(i);
                        Log.i(TAG,"Pokemon: "+p.getName());

                    }

                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG,"onResponse: "+response.errorBody());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PokemonRespuesta> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG,"OnFailure: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

¿alguien sabe cual es el problema?

Comment: Que sistema operativo tiene tu dispositivo?

Comment: la versión de 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a Bhavit S. Sengar desde Stackoverflow en ingles, es un bug de android < 4.4 ya que SSL es viejo debe usarse TLS
Aqui les dejó la respuesta traducida y con la explicacion completa de por que y como solucionarlo

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30302235/1669574

Encontré la solucion analizando los paquetes de datos usando Wireshark.
Lo que encontré es que mientras se hace una conexion segura, Android se regresa a **SSLv3** desde **TLSv1**.

Esto es un bug en vesiones de Android < 4.4, y puede ser resuleto removiento el protocolo SSLv3 desde la lista de protocolos disponibles.

Hice un SocketFactory personalizado llamado NoSSLv3SocketFactory.java

```
/*Copyright 2015 Bhavit Singh Sengar
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.*/

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedListener;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;


public class NoSSLv3SocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory{
    private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

public NoSSLv3SocketFactory() {
    this.delegate = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
}

public NoSSLv3SocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

private Socket makeSocketSafe(Socket socket) {
    if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
        socket = new NoSSLv3SSLSocket((SSLSocket) socket);
    }
    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}

private class NoSSLv3SSLSocket extends DelegateSSLSocket {

    private NoSSLv3SSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
        super(delegate);

    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
        if (protocols != null && protocols.length == 1 && "SSLv3".equals(protocols[0])) {

            List<String> enabledProtocols = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(delegate.getEnabledProtocols()));
            if (enabledProtocols.size() > 1) {
                enabledProtocols.remove("SSLv3");
                System.out.println("Removed SSLv3 from enabled protocols");
            } else {
                System.out.println("SSL stuck with protocol available for " + String.valueOf(enabledProtocols));
            }
            protocols = enabledProtocols.toArray(new String[enabledProtocols.size()]);
        }

        super.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
    }
}

public class DelegateSSLSocket extends SSLSocket {

    protected final SSLSocket delegate;

    DelegateSSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getEnabledCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getEnabledCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabledCipherSuites(String[] suites) {
        delegate.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedProtocols() {
        return delegate.getSupportedProtocols();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getEnabledProtocols() {
        return delegate.getEnabledProtocols();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
        delegate.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
    }

    @Override
    public SSLSession getSession() {
        return delegate.getSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void addHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener listener) {
        delegate.addHandshakeCompletedListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener listener) {
        delegate.removeHandshakeCompletedListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void startHandshake() throws IOException {
        delegate.startHandshake();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUseClientMode(boolean mode) {
        delegate.setUseClientMode(mode);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUseClientMode() {
        return delegate.getUseClientMode();
    }

    @Override
    public void setNeedClientAuth(boolean need) {
        delegate.setNeedClientAuth(need);
    }

    @Override
    public void setWantClientAuth(boolean want) {
        delegate.setWantClientAuth(want);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getNeedClientAuth() {
        return delegate.getNeedClientAuth();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getWantClientAuth() {
        return delegate.getWantClientAuth();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnableSessionCreation(boolean flag) {
        delegate.setEnableSessionCreation(flag);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getEnableSessionCreation() {
        return delegate.getEnableSessionCreation();
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(SocketAddress localAddr) throws IOException {
        delegate.bind(localAddr);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        delegate.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr) throws IOException {
        delegate.connect(remoteAddr);
    }

    @Override
    public void connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr, int timeout) throws IOException {
        delegate.connect(remoteAddr, timeout);
    }

    @Override
    public SocketChannel getChannel() {
        return delegate.getChannel();
    }

    @Override
    public InetAddress getInetAddress() {
        return delegate.getInetAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return delegate.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getKeepAlive() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getKeepAlive();
    }

    @Override
    public InetAddress getLocalAddress() {
        return delegate.getLocalAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public int getLocalPort() {
        return delegate.getLocalPort();
    }

    @Override
    public SocketAddress getLocalSocketAddress() {
        return delegate.getLocalSocketAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getOOBInline() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getOOBInline();
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return delegate.getOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public int getPort() {
        return delegate.getPort();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getReceiveBufferSize() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getReceiveBufferSize();
    }

    @Override
    public SocketAddress getRemoteSocketAddress() {
        return delegate.getRemoteSocketAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getReuseAddress() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getReuseAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getSendBufferSize() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getSendBufferSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSoLinger() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getSoLinger();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getSoTimeout() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getSoTimeout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getTcpNoDelay() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getTcpNoDelay();
    }

    @Override
    public int getTrafficClass() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getTrafficClass();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBound() {
        return delegate.isBound();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isClosed() {
        return delegate.isClosed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConnected() {
        return delegate.isConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInputShutdown() {
        return delegate.isInputShutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOutputShutdown() {
        return delegate.isOutputShutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendUrgentData(int value) throws IOException {
        delegate.sendUrgentData(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setKeepAlive(boolean keepAlive) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setKeepAlive(keepAlive);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOOBInline(boolean oobinline) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setOOBInline(oobinline);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPerformancePreferences(int connectionTime, int latency, int bandwidth) {
        delegate.setPerformancePreferences(connectionTime, latency, bandwidth);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setReceiveBufferSize(int size) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setReceiveBufferSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    public void setReuseAddress(boolean reuse) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setReuseAddress(reuse);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setSendBufferSize(int size) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setSendBufferSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSoLinger(boolean on, int timeout) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setSoLinger(on, timeout);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setSoTimeout(int timeout) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setSoTimeout(timeout);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTcpNoDelay(boolean on) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setTcpNoDelay(on);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTrafficClass(int value) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setTrafficClass(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdownInput() throws IOException {
        delegate.shutdownInput();
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdownOutput() throws IOException {
        delegate.shutdownOutput();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return delegate.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return delegate.equals(o);
    }
}
}
```

Usa esta clase mientras se hace la conexion

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
sslcontext.init(null, null, null);
SSLSocketFactory NoSSLv3Factory = new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(NoSSLv3Factory);
l_connection = (HttpsURLConnection) l_url.openConnection();
l_connection.connect();
```

**UPDATE :**

Ahora, la solucion correcta podria ser instalar un nuevo proveedor para l seguridad desde [Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller.html):

```
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
```

Efectivamente esto le dara accesos a tu aplicacion a versiones más nuevas de OpenSSL y de Java Security, que incluya soporte para TLSv1.2 in SSLEngine.
Una vez el nuevo proveedor este instalado puedes usar SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 de esta manera

```
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sslContext.init(null, null, null);
    SSLEngine engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
```

O puedes restringir los protocolos habilitados usando `engine.setEnabledProtocols`.

No olvides agregar la siguiente dependecia ([latest version found here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
```

Para más información  [link](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html).

Answer (score 0):

Podrias colocar el log para saber que error es que te presenta?

Pero de paso te digo que agregues la dependencia del Interceptor para que tambien veas lo que envias:

En tu gradle agrega:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
```

Y en donde hagas la instancia de retrofit:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
        .build();
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();
```

Chequea que tengas los siguientes permisos en tu AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda que para pedir aclaraciones sobre la pregunta se debe realizar en comentarios, revisa [answer], saludos!

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys, eso lo tengo claro (vengo del en). Recuerda que se necesitan una cantidad minima de puntos de reputacion para comentar.